# Problem adding new group in a specific target type

Tags: targetgroups

We are having problems when adding one or more groups to a specific target type. We get the following message: **Tridion Link has invalid value. The item tcm: 0-XXXX-65568 does not exist.**

This happens only in some target type, in others it works correctly. Can anyone guide us on what may be happening?

Regards and thanks a lot for your help,
Sergio.-

Answer (score 4):

Looking at the following SDL Support article, it appears that your issue may be a bug in the product:

https://gateway.sdl.com/apex/communityknowledge?articleName=000004453

You'll probably have to open a ticket with Support to resolve.